# How can I align HTML divs in a row like structure?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align some divs in a horizontal row structure.  There is a div `container` which has child divs, and these child divs should be in the same row.  There can be many container divs like these, having different ids but the same class name.

How can I do that?  Here is the jsFiddle I attempted: http://jsfiddle.net/unix_user/VSd6Y/6/.

Comment: @Wex: by how? I am asking the questions which I am not able to answer or find on google. I am not an experienced person and a beginner to this

Comment: @unix_user By going over your previously asked questions and selecting one of the answers as the chosen one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block`. This way your `div` will stack up next to each other *and* you are able to specify widths and other attributes common to `block` elements.

Check out the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSd6Y/12/). You can see that the `div`s styled with `container` are on separate lines, but the child `div`s are stacked next to each other.

Comment: Can you please give me a small jsfiddle. I am able to stack it up on column wise but not row wise.

Comment: I did tried this. But when I open the html page in browser, all the divs are aligned next to each other. I dont want that to happen. The container divs should be placed one below the other, and this is what I am not able to do so

Comment: Don't style the container divs then. Just have them as normal. Only style the inner divs to be `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as a `UL LI` structure. You can either `float:left;` the elements or `display:inline-block;` for new browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing something with a .class like:

```
.repeating{width:400px; height:100px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}    
.repeatMe{width:90px; height:100px; padding:0px 5px; float:left;}



<div id="repeating">
<div class="repeatMe"><img src="imghere.gif" /></div>
<div class="repeatMe"><img src="imghere.gif" /></div>
<div class="repeatMe"><img src="imghere.gif" /></div>
<div class="repeatMe"><img src="imghere.gif" /></div>
</div>
```