# HTML div tags on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get some HTML code side by side and not having any luck.  Pretty new to this stuff.

Here is the code (please disregard the border stuff, that is just there to help me).  I force a specific width (250px) so I can guarantee buttons stay on one line because the html to the right of button can be hidden depending on the options.

```html
<div style="flex:0 0 auto;border:1px dashed green;">
  <ul class="instructions" style="border:3px dashed blue;">
    <li>
      <strong>Instructions:</strong>
      <span data-bind="html: instructionLabelView"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div style="width:250px;border:1px solid red;text-align:right;vertical-align:top;float:right;">
    <button type="button" class="webcms-button-default" title="Submit a request to start a new report in the database." data-bind="click: onNewReportButtonActivated, visible: hasSearched() && !hasResults() && $root.startNewReportEnabled()">Start New Report</button>
    <button type="reset" class="webcms-button-default" title="Reset all search criteria.">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" class="webcms-button-default" title="Submit a search for results that match your defined criteria above." data-bind="enable: !$root.isSearching()">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if image can be seen, hopefully it uploads so people can view it.

Comment: .instructions {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
    }

Comment: @KaanBurakSener they are inline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I align HTML divs in a row like structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187997/how-can-i-align-html-divs-in-a-row-like-structure) and a multitude of other similar answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` to your container and `flex-grow: 1` to your ul:

```html
<div style="flex:0 0 auto;border:1px dashed green;display:flex;">
  <ul class="instructions" style="border:3px dashed blue;flex-grow:1;">
    <li>
      <strong>Instructions:</strong>
      <span data-bind="html: instructionLabelView"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div style="width:250px;border:1px solid red;text-align:right;vertical-align:top;">
    <button type="button" class="webcms-button-default" title="Submit a request to start a new report in the database." data-bind="click: onNewReportButtonActivated, visible: hasSearched() && !hasResults() && $root.startNewReportEnabled()">Start New Report</button>
    <button type="reset" class="webcms-button-default" title="Reset all search criteria.">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" class="webcms-button-default" title="Submit a search for results that match your defined criteria above." data-bind="enable: !$root.isSearching()">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the `float:right` from your button div as it now makes no difference if it is there or not

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100%; float: left; flex:0 0 auto;border:1px dashed green;">
     <ul class="instructions" style="width: 40%; float: left;border:3px dashed blue; margin: 0">
    <li>
      <strong>Instructions:</strong>
      <span data-bind="html: instructionLabelView"></span>
    </li>
     </ul>
     <div style="border:1px solid red;text-align:right;vertical-align:top;float:right;">
    <button type="button" title="Submit a request to start a new report in the database." data-bind="click: onNewReportButtonActivated, visible: hasSearched() && !hasResults() && $root.startNewReportEnabled()">Start New Report</button>
    <button type="reset" title="Reset all search criteria.">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" title="Submit a search for results that match your defined criteria above." data-bind="enable: !$root.isSearching()">Search</button>
     </div>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help.

In styling use `display:flex;` to get contents on one line.

You can also change the direction of the flex.

Refer to this website for the best [examples](http://flexbox.help/).